Using TextJoin and IFBLANK to return two different cells values if a cell is blank?
I am trying to use a combo of textjoin and ifblank to return the values in two different rows if a certain cell is blank, one after the other with a comma as the delimiter. However, I can't get the formula to do this without listing first all cells from row A, then row B.
My formula as it stands is
=TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,IF(ISBLANK('Proposed Dataset'!F2:F10),'Proposed Dataset'!A2:A10,""),IF(ISBLANK('Proposed Dataset'!F2:F10),'Proposed Dataset'!B2:B10,""))

I've tried throwing an ampersand into the formula to have output combine A2:10 and B2:10 but this doesn't work. I feel like there is a really obvious solution here I'm overlooking, any advice?
Values output as 2 lists one after the other

If you're trying to get joined text in separate rows, could you try
=VSTACK(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,IF(ISBLANK('Proposed Dataset'!F2:F10),'Proposed Dataset'!A2:A10,"")),TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,IF(ISBLANK('Proposed Dataset'!F2:F10),'Proposed Dataset'!B2:B10,"")))
Or, not sure whether this is what you need
=IF(COUNTIF(F2:F10,""),VSTACK(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A2:A10),TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,B2:B10)),"")
VSTACK is available in Microsoft 365.

This gets me the same results, so to clarify- If there is a blank field in F2, I want the output to be " (A2 cell contents), (B2 cell contents)"
For example, if A2 is blank, my formula cell should return "Tim, 12/5/24". My date in this example is in text format so doesn't need to be altered.
Learning how Vstack works is super nifty though, thanks, that's going on my list of useful formula!

Thanks for clarifying, could this help: =IF(ISBLANK(F2:F10),BYROW(HSTACK(A2:A10,B2:B10),LAMBDA(cells,TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,cells))),"")

Yes, that's exactly what I'm after! Thankyou very much :)
